# MS-Word 2013 & 2016 Doesn't Have Numeral And Month Name Option in Show Document Content menu Section

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word

How can I have the numeral and month name option back?

[image: This is my Menu]

Comment: I don't have anything related to month names or numerals in that section of the Word Options dialog. (Word 2013: File, Options, Advanced). Can you provide more information about what it is you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

save your work in word.

Go to Menu - File - Options - Languages

in [Add additional Editing Languages] open the drop down box, select Some version of Arabic (say Arabic (Soudy Arabia) ).

Click on Add button at the right.

That will add the language in Editing languages, though you need not enable either.

[image]

It will then ask to restart word. Let it.

Once the word reopens, you will find those fields there.

[image]